# LARAVEL - Whenever I refresh the page, it continuously sending a data to the table

Tags: laravel-10

Whenever I refresh the page, it continuously sending a data to the table

I tried POST method but "The GET method is not supported for route communication/assignto. Supported methods: POST." message always appear.

this is my routes:

```
Route::controller(TrackerController::class)->prefix('communication')->group(function () {
    //Route::get('assign/{id}', 'assign')->name('tracker.assign');
    Route::post('assignto', 'assignto')->name('tracker.assignto');
});
```